# How to use channel.Qos, channel.basicAck in my handleDelivery() of DefaultConsumer?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am using new DefaultConsumer(channel) and overriding handleDeliverymethod.
My goal is to use my consumer as worker queues and for that I know that I have to provide the channel.basicQos(1). Using 1 as my prefetchCount. I have been reading that I also need to provide channel.basicAck in order for my server to know how many unacknowledged messages must be sent(correct me if I am wrong here). Based on this count the channel.basicQos takes effect. Now, I am using the following statements in the handleDelivery method

```
channel.basicQos(1);
channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
```

The issue is, I keep getting the following error:

```
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: clean connection shutdown;
reason: Attempt to use closed channel
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:190)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:223)
.................................
..................................
```

When I remove the channel.basicAck, I don't see that problem.
How can I use the channel.basicQos to work (My understanding is for this to work, I need to provide the basicAck) and I don't want to get the AlreadyClosedException error. 
Thanks for taking the time to read this and for any help you guys can offer!

Comment: I went to the rabbitmq log and saw this message - {amqp_error,precondition_failed,"unknown delivery tag 1",'basic.ack'}. This gave me the idea that something was wrong with the ack and double checked channel.basicConsume and found that autoAck was set to true. Changed it to false and now everything works fine.

Comment: Have you checked that you are not in autoAck mode?

Comment: Right. That was the problem. In my previous comment I mentioned that the autoAck was set to true. I changed it to false and now my acks are being used.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I skipped your first comment